# How to find the type of document in ionic2 file chooser and file transfer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

how can I find the document type i.e. pdf or docx while choosing the file through Filechooser & send it to the server.

Comment: check extension

Comment: Yes , may be I can do that on the server side but I want on client side while choosing the file only it should give error if doc type not pdf or docx. But I am not getting enough reference. Thanks